# WIFI connection Vb.net and Esp32 wroom 32 send and receive

Tags: vb.net, tcp, wifi, esp32, arduino-ide

My project is a mobile robot, automated and connected to a PC via WIFI or RF, the PC program is on VB.Net. I have managed to connect to the WIFI of my house and send data to the Visual Basic Net program, but I can't read the `ACK` response that I send to ESP32 after each data reading.

My question is how to get this communication of sending response between an ESP32 and Visual Basic Net (in which I have threads for the connections and controls of forms). In particular I see what the ESP32 sends but in the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE I cannot see the ACK sent by VBNet to the ESP32. The ESP32 option with sending data to a WEBSERVER is not valid for me since I use VBNet and I do it from Windows forms.

The message that I send to VBnet and viewed in a form is like this `$5#5@125*`, after decoded only 125 is showed in a text box.

VBNet form

[image: VBNet form]

If someone have a answer will be appreciated.

ESP32 code:

```c
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
const char* ssid = "************";
const char* password =  "***************";
const char * host = "192.168.1.35"; 
const uint16_t port = 3818;
int c,tout;
int Device;
String DatoStr,Str0;
char Respuesta;

int indice,Ind;
boolean NextMsg;
void WiFiStationConnected(WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info)
{
    Serial.println("Connected to AP!");
    
    Serial.print("SSID Length: ");
    Serial.println(info.connected.ssid_len);
 
    Serial.print("SSID: ");
    for(int i=0; i<info.connected.ssid_len; i++){
      Serial.print((char) info.connected.ssid[i]);
    }
 
    Serial.print("\nBSSID: ");
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
      Serial.printf("%02X", info.connected.bssid[i]);
 
      if(i<5){
        Serial.print(":");
      }
    }
     
    Serial.print("\nChannel: ");
    Serial.println(info.connected.channel);
 
    Serial.print("Auth mode: ");
    Serial.println(info.connected.authmode);
      
} 
  
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 WiFi.onEvent(WiFiStationConnected, SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED);
 WiFi.onEvent([](WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info){
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  }, SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP);  
    
    
}

void loop(){
  String line;
  c=c+1;
  WiFiClient client;
   if (client.connect(host, port)){
     Ind=0;
      Str0=String("$1#5@");
      Str0+=c;
      DatoStr +=Str0+"*";
      client.print(DatoStr);
      Serial.println(DatoStr);
      if (client.available()){
         for(Ind=0;Ind=2;Ind++)
         {
           char DatoServer  = client.read();
           Respuesta +=DatoServer;
         }
         Serial.print("Respuesta: ");
         Serial.println(Respuesta);
         Serial.println("");
      }
      Serial.println("Disconnecting...");
      client.stop();
      Str0="";
      DatoStr="";
      NextMsg = false;
   }
   delay(100);
   if (c==20) 
    {
     c=0;
    }
  }`
```

VBnet process exchange message

```vb
Private Sub Listening()
    Dim DatoDecodificado As String
    Dim Mensaje As String
    ' CREATE LISTENER LOOP

    Do Until IsListening = False
        RaiseEvent Started(Me, "Servidor ON")
        ' ACCEPT INCOMING CONNECTIONS
        If ServTCP.Pending = True Then
            Cliente = ServTCP.AcceptTcpClient
            ClientData = New StreamReader(Cliente.GetStream)
            ' RAISE EVENT FOR INCOMING MESSAGES
            Try
                Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = Cliente.GetStream()
                DatoDecodificado = DecodificaMsg(ClientData.ReadLine)
                RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, DatoDecodificado)
                Mensaje = "ACK" & DatoDecodificado & vbCr
                Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Mensaje)
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                Dim MensajeToShow As String = "ACK" & DatoDecodificado
                RaiseEvent MessageSended(Me, MensajeToShow)
                'IsListening = False
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End If
        ' REDUCE CPU USAGE
        'Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement an HTTP server on the ESP32 (there's an example source included with IDF) and code it as a WebAPI, then use the HTTP client capabilities in .Net to send commands and read status, as JSON or XML.

That way you can use industry standard stuff like Newtonsoft to send serialized objects to the ESP32 (there is also JSON parsing functionality in IDF) and turn the returned data into objects in .Net.  It would even be easily possible to create a controller client in HTML/JavaScript.

It's efficient and intuitive, and will free you from needing to code packet-level details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it as an easy way but im looking for the perfect example for my protocol :
Send Message------>PC (VB.Net with standard Windows forms) reading message, decoding it and answer to ESP32 one ACK to controlling the good way on transmission so can send other message o reapeat if anything is wrong.. This is my little big problem now